# How to Add Jface Support to project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am new to Eclipse environment.

I have Eclipse Indigo.
Using I've downloaded the following via Install new Software:
Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment and
Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources

I created a new Java project, in java build path libraries tab I clicked on Add Library selected plugin dependencies but the list is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options to use JFace. You can either create a plug-in project (instead of Java project), and then you can use plug-in dependencies in the manifest.mf editor.

However, I believe, you want to use JFace in a standalone Java application. In this case you have to obtain the corresponding jar files manually, and add them to the project, but not as plug-in dependencies, but as normal jar dependencies. For details about this latter method check the JFace wiki page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Create_the_Eclipse_SWT.2FJFace_Project

Comment: I've followed the tutorial (second link) up to the section 18, where I should set up the sources for Jface. the problem  is that there is no directory called org.eclipse.rcp that contains the sources, though I've downloaded the  Eclipse Platform Plug-in Developer Resources

Comment: In my installation the required jar file is not in org.eclipse.rcp, but directly under the plugins folder. Maybe its the same for you.